# mysql update right after committed transaction can't see records

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am performing a transaction using a connection. Whenever a second connection immediately tries to update the rows just inserted, the rows are not found. Even if the transaction was committed before issuing an UPDATE.

I have the mysql query log which describes the scenario.

The last statement fails with 0 rows affected (`UPDATE refresh_token...`) :

```
2018-08-03T13:31:24.829038Z  1150 Query START TRANSACTION
2018-08-03T13:31:24.830026Z  1150 Prepare   INSERT INTO account (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.830493Z  1150 Execute   INSERT INTO account (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.831345Z  1150 Close stmt
2018-08-03T13:31:24.833228Z  1150 Prepare   INSERT INTO refresh_token (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.833666Z  1150 Execute   INSERT INTO refresh_token (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.834356Z  1150 Close stmt
2018-08-03T13:31:24.834477Z  1150 Prepare   INSERT INTO another (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.835155Z  1150 Execute   INSERT INTO another (<redacted>) VALUES (<redacted>)
2018-08-03T13:31:24.835621Z  1150 Close stmt
2018-08-03T13:31:24.835747Z  1150 Query COMMIT
2018-08-03T13:31:24.840374Z  1150 Prepare   UPDATE refresh_token SET accessed = ? WHERE token = ?
2018-08-03T13:31:24.840799Z  1150 Execute   UPDATE refresh_token SET accessed = '<redacted>' WHERE token = '<redacted>'
2018-08-03T13:31:24.843346Z  1150 Close stmt
```

If I wait 500ms before issuing the `UPDATE refresh_token SET...`, the record is found.

Here is the transaction isolation level:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
'REPEATABLE-READ', 'REPEATABLE-READ'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK turns out the granularity of the `DATETIME` column is in seconds. So inserting and updating with `NOW()` makes the record appear as exactly the same, so mysql reports `0 rows updated`.